# sibling elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having trouble selecting certain elements in the DOM. What I'm trying to do is toggle the class of a div to show and hide the content by using a link, then change the link text in conjunction to it.

My code now affects all links and divs at the same time and that of course is not what I want. I want the div above the link to be affected as well as the link text to "Show less." Below is the HTML, and jQuery.

```
<body>
<section id="jdom">
    <h1>Murach's JavaScript and DOM Scripting</h1>
    <h2>Book description</h2>
    <div>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>           

    <h2>About the author</h2>
    <div>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>

    <h2>Who this book is for</h2>
    <div>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide"> 
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure    there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>               

</section>
</body>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).ready (function () {
$("a").toggle (
    function() {
        $("div").toggleClass();
        $("a").text("Show less");
    },

    function() {
        $("div").toggleClass();
        $("a").text("Show more");
    }
); //end toggle
}); //end ready
```

Comment: Toggle event is depracated in jquery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 : http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        var div = $(this).prev("div").toggleClass('hide');
        $(this).text(div.hasClass('hide') ? "Show more" : "Show less");
    });
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ozaduc/1/)

Note that the usage of `toggle` taking two functions as arguments has been deprecated. It's easy to build a shim but you generally don't need it.

Comment: Aww faster than me, +1 anyway!

Answer (score 2):

As the target element is the previous sibling, you can use `.prev()` method:

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
    $(this).text(function(_, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Show more' ? 'Show less' : 'Show more';
    }).prev('div').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4s7QJ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#jdom a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hide  = $(this).prev('.hide'),
            state = !hide.is(':visible');

        hide.toggle(state);
        $(this).text(state ? 'Show less' : 'Show more');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XeFTF/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `this` to find the closest elements to toggle.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var that = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev(".hide").toggle(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            that.text("Show Less");
        } else {
            that.text("Show More");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The missing `}` hurts my eye.

Comment: I'm no doc, but I hope that fix helps your eye :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Short, sweet and don't use a depracated function.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var el = $(this),
        prev = el.prev();

    prev.toggleClass('hide');
    el.text(prev.hasClass('hide') ? 'Show more' : 'Show less');
})
```